# How to bulk edit File property details of a file in windows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, batch-file, file-management

Is there software or any solution by which I can edit the comment section of a video file in bulk?

So basically I have an excel sheet which has captions of a bunch of video files as shown below:
[image: captions of video file in excel csv file]

What I need to do is to be able to copy the caption in this excel sheet to the File property 'comment' section of the corresponding video files that are shown in the first column in the above screenshot.

[image: file property comment section of the video file]

As you can see this is the field that I want to be able to populate using the caption from the excel sheet. I would be really happy if anyone can suggest me a solution to how I can achieve this using any software. I tried searching online a lot but couldn't find any software that would be able to help me with this task.

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: While there are tools to edit the EXIF data, https://www.geckoandfly.com/7987/how-to-change-exif-data-date-and-camera-properties-with-free-editor/ , and AnalogExif states it can "copy metadata from another file", I've not tried any of these tools for a batch operation. You might post at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ , *instead*, if you do not get answers in a week or two.

Comment: @BlindSpots Yes, I want to change the Metadata - specifically the comment section of the metadata and add captions from the csv file. This csv file contains the captions in one column and the file location in another column. 

The file format is MP4.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I just went through all the software mentioned in that blog you shared, it seems like there isn't any software that edits metadata for the video file and has the option to import it from a CSV file so that the caption can be added in the comments for the appropriate file(video).

Comment: @ShijilKumar, Someone familiar with EXIF tool (https://exiftool.org/) and programming or scripting might write a script to read each line of the CSV, and then modify the file EXIF data, but, as you state, there does not seem to be a tool to do both. Sorry I could not help.

Comment: @ShijilKumar I provided an approach that will work.  Let me know if you run into problems.  By default `ExifTool` will backup the original files before writing changes.  **NB** your file paths in your image incorporate both front slashes and back slashes .  You will need to do a cleanup of that if planning to work from absolute paths

Answer (score 0):

##### ExifTool by Phil Harvey

The [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) will allow you to replace the value of the `Comment` tag in a group of files using a CSV file as the source.

##### CSV file format

1. `mp4` files for each batch need to be in the same folder (see note at end)
2. `csv` column headings must be identical to what is shown in `A1:B1` below

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **SourceFile** | **Comment** |
| **2** | D:\myFolder\034572_838638.mp4 | absolute path, blah blah |
| **3** | ..\myFolder\034572_838638.mp4 | relative path, blah blah |
| **4** | .\034572_838638.mp4 | relative path, blah blah |
| **4** | 034572_838638.mp4 | relative path, blah blah |

##### Write to MP4s

Depending on the current working directory and the locations of your exifTool, csv, and mp4 files, your command could be

```
# Absolute

C:\exiftool-12.52\exiftool -csv=D:\csv\list.csv D:\downloads\*.mp4


# Relative (and all in CWD)

exiftool -csv=list.csv *.mp4


# Based on

{exiftool_path} -csv={csv_filePath} {mp4_filePath}
```

##### Read from MP4s

You could also generate a `csv` based on a fileset and existing tags. Using the same paths as the previous example

```
# Absolute

C:\exiftool-12.52\exiftool -comment -csv D:\downloads\*.mp4 > D:\csv\list.csv


# Relative (and all in CWD)

exiftool -comment -csv *.mp4 > list.csv


# based on 

{exiftool_path} -comment -csv {mp4_filePath} > {csv_filePath}
```

- CSV Documentation: [exiftool.org #csv-CSVFILE](https://ttps://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#csv-CSVFILE)
- ExifTool Installation: [exiftool.org/install](https://exiftool.org/install.html)

**Note:**  If you have batches of `mp4` files in sepparate folders, you need to run the ExifTool once for each folder.  You could share the same `csv` if that is helpful, and it would then generate non-fatal error messages for any mismatches on that run.